# Git-tfs fetch and diff

Tags: git, version-control, tfs, git-tfs

I've been using [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs) and been doing `git tfs pull` all the time. Now I'm trying to find a way to see diff before merging after `git tfs fetch` and can't find a way. `git remote` doesn't show a tfs repo as a remote.

Comment: What are you trying to see?  The changes made upstream before you merge them into your local branch?

Comment: that's right, exactly what I wanna do

Comment: If you do `git branch -r`, does the remote TFS branch show up there?  If it does, you can diff your local branch with it.

Comment: oh yeah.. it shows it as  tfs/default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `git remote` doesn't show a tfs repo as a remote.

That's wrong! When you clone a tfs repository with git-tfs, there is a `tfs/default` that is created.
And that's the remote that are updated when you do a `git tfs fetch`.
Consequently, you could do a `git diff tfs/default` to see differences between your master and `tfs/default` remote.

If you use git-tfs to manage TFS branches, there is even a remote for each branch...

Perhaps, you could even use the `git tfs branch` command to see branches informations (if you have a recent version of git-tfs)